# How to generate a "named destination" in PDF?

Tags: hyperref, pdf, labels, viewers, bookmarks

According to the Evince help, one can open a PDF at the location of a "named destination":

```
SYNTAX
       evince [--help]  [--page-label=PAGE |  --page-index=NUM‐
       BER | --named-dest=DEST] [--fullscreen] [--presentation]
       [--preview] [--find=STRING] [filename(s)...]
...
       -n, --named-dest=DEST
              Open the document on the specified named destina‐
              tion.
```

In Acrobat (`acroread`) the corresponding command is ([documentation](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/pdf_open_parameters.pdf))

```
acroread /a "nameddest=pos2" hyperref.pdf
```

**How can I generate such *named destinations* in a PDF from LaTeX?**

In the past, (mainly for Acrobat) I used the `zref-savepos` package to open the document at a desired location (set at compilation). This doesn't seem to work well with Evince.

The question is not so much about Evince but what is that Evince calls "named destination" and how to produce them.

Below it is a series of attempts I made. When running Evince I get the following messages:

```
$ evince hyperref.pdf -n pos3 #or pos2
failed to look up pos3
failed to look up pos3
```

MWE

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{pdfstartview=FitBH \hypercalcbp{\zposy{pos2}sp}} %open at pos2 (works only in Acrobat)
\usepackage{bookmark}
\usepackage{zref-savepos}
\begin{document}

\zsavepos{pos1}

Bla

\zsavepos{pos2}

Ble

\belowpdfbookmark{Pos3}{pos3}

Bli

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In my point of view, it's sufficient to set a `\hypertarget{destname}{}` and use the destname as argument to the evince `--named-dest` option. This works at least in my evince version (3.6.1, very old, I believe)

It works with Acrobat Reader as well, the calling syntax is slightly different, however:

> acroread /a "nameddest=pos2" nameddestexample.pdf

to open the file at the named destination (hypertarget) "pos2".

```
\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{hyperref}
%\hypersetup{pdfstartview=FitBH \hypercalcbp{\zposy{pos2}sp}} %open at pos2 (works only in Acrobat)
\usepackage{bookmark}
\begin{document}


Bla

\blindtext[1]
\hypertarget{pos1}{}%



Ble
\blindtext[5]
\hypertarget{pos2}{}%


Bli

\blindtext[10]
\hypertarget{pos3}{Blue}

\blindtext[10]

\hypertarget{pos4}{Blofeld}



\end{document}
```

Comment: No, you don't even need the `bookmark` package for this, but the `\hypertarget` feature is useful, if you want to generate arbitray bookmarks with `\bookmark[dest=destname]{Bookmark entry}`, by the way. (In this case, you need the `bookmark` package however) -- Regarding `evince` and `acroread` ... different programmers, different interfaces ... :-(