# Add destinations for external links to PDF file?

Tags: pdf, labels, links

According to [this document](https://helpx.adobe.com/acrobat/kb/link-html-pdf-page-acrobat.html), it is possible to add "destinations" to a PDF file that can be used to navigate directly to certain places in the document when opening it:

> **Open a PDF file to a set destination**
>
> A destination is the end point of a link represented by text in the
>   Destinations tab. Destinations enable you to set navigation paths
>   across a collection of Adobe PDF documents. Linking to a destination
>   is recommended when linking across documents because, unlike a link to
>   a page, a link to a destination is not affected by the addition or
>   deletion of pages within the target document.
>
> To set a Destination in Acrobat 7.0 (Professional or Standard):
>
> 1. Set the Zoom and page location to the way you want it on the screen.
> 2. Select View > Navigation Tabs > Destinations to open the Destinations tab.
> 3. Select Options > New Destination from the Destinations tab.
> 4. Give the Destination a name.
> 5. Create an HTML link that points to this destination by adding #[destination name] to the end of the links URL.
>
> For example, this HTML tag opens a destination named "glossary" in a
>   PDF file named myfile.pdf:
>
> `<A HREF="http://www.example.com/myfile.pdf#glossary">`

Using pdflatex and hyperref, is there a way to place these "destinations" in the PDF output file? Is it possible to automatically add `\label`s as destinations?

Comment: I'm not sure to understand what you want to do, but it could be related with http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/6210/can-you-have-hyperlinks-to-locations-in-different-pdfs

Comment: @Ignasi: Related, yes, but in that example, the link is between two PDF documents. I need to reference a certain point in a PDF file from a HTML page.

Comment: How about this one: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/213860/how-to-generate-a-named-destination-in-pdf

Comment: Then, I think you are looking for this one: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/25919/external-html-link-to-a-specific-page-of-a-pdf-file?rq=1

Comment: @Ignasi: No, since I need to link to a (moving) symbolic target, not a fixed page number.